# Get data quoted by ' using RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, coffeescript

I hava a sting like `ptui('Sub1','Sub2','Sub3');` I want to get an array from this string and the format looks like `['Sub1', 'Sub2', 'Sub3']`. Can anyone write a RegExp in JavaScript or CoffeeScript to implement this?

Comment: Please show us what you tried and what went wrong.

Comment: Hi, thank you! As I say I tried I try repl = s.match(/'[^']*'/g) but I get ['\'Sub1\'','\'Sub2\'','\'Sub3\''] instead of ['Sub1', 'Sub2', 'Sub3'].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
var s = "ptui('Sub1','Sub2','Sub3');";
var repl = '[' + s.match(/'[^']*'/g).join(", ") + ']';

//=> ['Sub1', 'Sub2', 'Sub3']
```

Comment: Hi, thank you a lot! I want to get an array and I try repl = s.match(/'[^']*'/g) but I get ['\'Sub1\'','\'Sub2\'','\'Sub3\''] instead of ['Sub1', 'Sub2', 'Sub3'].

Comment: If you want an array then `var arr = s.match(/'[^']*'/g);` is what you need.

Comment: Hi, yes, i tried this. But I will get ['\'Sub1\'','\'Sub2\'','\'Sub3\''] instead of ['Sub1', 'Sub2', 'Sub3']. Sorry can you tell me how to remove \'?

Comment: See this jsfiddle for verification: http://jsfiddle.net/Z85pw/ and try to reproduce your code on jsfiddle to demonstrate

Comment: I am using coffee script. But it seems not work for me. Anyway I will try and thank you very very much.